# NP-completeness and difficulty of all possible solutions

Tags: np-complete

Take the SAT problem (or any other NP-complete).

Is the set of all possible combinations of SAT problems are NP-complete?

Or maybe there are combinations that can be quickly solved?

If I take a random logical formula of n variables is always always be NP-complete problem? There are no exceptions for any particular forms of formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all subsets of SAT are NP-complete.  [Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem) identifies infinite subsets of SAT that are in P, with the remainder being NP-complete.  The known subsets that are in P are [2-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability), [HORN-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability), ANTIHORN-SAT, [XOR-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#XOR-satisfiability) and SAT instances that can be satisfied with all-true or all-false assignments.

Comment: Also, SAT for some non-clausal representations like DNF and BDDs is in P.